# using replace to remove part of url

Tags: javascript, php

my issue: i need to remove part of the directory to be able to use as url in a for loop setup.

php file

```
header('Content-type: application/json');

echo json_encode(array(
    "name" => "website",
    "type" => "folder",
    "path" => $dir,
    "items" => $response
));
```

i have two functions
path which is usr/www/account/website/folder1/img.png
paths with replace function should be /folder1/img.png
**am receiving error as undefined when its in a For loop but works fine without the loop, what am i doing wrong?**

```
if(scannedFiles.length) {

                scannedFiles.forEach(function(f) {
                    var paths = f.path.replace('usr/www/account/website', '');

                    var file = $('<li class="files"><a href="'+ f.paths +'" title="'+ f.paths +'" class="files">'+icon+'<span class="name">'+ name +'</span> <span class="details">'+fileSize+'</span></a></li>');
                    file.appendTo(fileList);
                });

            }
```

Comment: What is `undefined` exactly?

Comment: Wouldn't this be something you could better control and handle on the php side? Provide an extra basepath for the image that does not include your whole server structure exposed to the client? (because all of this: usr/www/account/website is unreachable by javascript/html/dom anyhow, so its needless to return it from php)

Comment: Hint: You create variable `paths` and never use it. Then you use a property `paths` (with an s) that doesn't exist in the data

Answer (score 0):

"f.paths" is unnecessary since its a local variable and is not extracted from an array so by changing it to "paths" it works

Answer (score 0):

```
var file = $('<li class="files"><a href="'+ f.paths +'" title="'+ f.paths +'" class="files">'+icon+'<span class="name">'+ name +'</span> <span class="details">'+fileSize+'</span></a></li>');
```

In your code, `f.paths` is `undefined`, you either need to used `paths` which is the replacement for `f.path` or use `f.path`, which is the original file path.

Comment: Not an either or situation. No point in doing the replace then use the orginal

Comment: Yes, I am not exactly sure what OP wants to use here, if he wants to use the original path then he should remove `paths` variable. But if he wants to use `paths` he should use path without the `f.`

Answer (score 0):

"f" in the below code refers to each item in the scannedFile and as you are trying to access f.paths will give the value if paths is a property of that object. If paths is not a property it gives you undefined.

You can modify your code as below

```
    if(scannedFiles.length) {    
                scannedFiles.forEach(function(f) {    
                    let replacedPath = f.path.replace('usr/www/account/website', '');

                    let file = $('<li class="files"><a href="'+ replacedPath +'" title="'+ replacedPath  +'" class="files">'+icon+'<span class="name">'+ name +'</span> <span class="details">'+fileSize+'</span></a></li>');
                    file.appendTo(fileList);
                });

            }
```